# Associative array passing as empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass an array to PHP via Ajax, but the array is being passed as an empty string. This is my code when creating the array:

```
var params = new Array();
var inputs = new Array();
inputs = $(":input");
$.each(inputs, function(key, value) {
  params[value.id] = value.value;
});

alert(params);
```

Before that there are around 20 inputs that look like this:

```
<input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" class="medium"/>
<input name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" class="medium"/>
```

The `alert(params)` is just giving me an empty string. However, `alert(params['first_name'])` actually gives me the `first_name` input value.

Why isn't the array going through?

Comment: so is it coming through as an empty string in PHP also? Are you serializing to JSON before the AJAX call? We'd really need to see the AJAX call and the PHP to work out what's going on

Comment: Because `Array`s only take numerical indexes. If you want an "associative array", use objects. *Note:* This also holds if you want to serialize it with JSON.

Comment: Not the exact answer, but if you want to send a form via ajax take a look at jQuery .serialize() http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: @Felix Just playing devil's advocate, but isn't that what he's doing? The only reason it isn't working is because he's not accessing them correctly.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: No, if you assign string properties to an array, most array operations will ignore them. Like transforming the array to a string (what happens with `alert`) or converting it to JSON with `JSON.stringify`. Whenever you have non-numerical properties, you have to use objects, not arrays (and just in case: yes, I know that arrays are objects too).

Comment: @Felix That's what I mean. His method of storing properties is fine, it's just that he then tries to *access* them with functions that only look at numerical indexes.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: Ah... ok, lets say it is fine because it is possible, but it is not the right way to do it ;) E.g. you cannot tell `JSON.stringify` to consider non-numerical properties of arrays.

Comment: yes i am serializing, etc. But the array is empty, it was working before when i was using params[0] = 'whatever', params[1] = 'this' but it is not working when using names.

Comment: @luqita: Because you should not use an array in that way. Use an object.

Comment: and how? would you please post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var params = new Array();
    var inputs = $(":input");

    $.each(inputs, function(key, value) {
        //I guess the problem was that params is array and your id's were strings
        //array's elements are arr[0], arr[1],
        //not like arr[firstname], arr[lastname], ...
        params[value.id] = value.value;  
    });
    alert(params);
});
//moved everything inside $(document).ready
```

with this -

```
<input name="first_name" id="0" value="1" type="text" class="medium"/>
<input name="last_name" id="1" value="2" type="text" class="medium"/>

<!-- Changed id's from string to numbers. -->
```

**Update:**

Also, try this it might help you understand whats going on -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var params = {}; //use object instead of array
    var inputs = $(":input");

    $.each(inputs, function(key, value) {                       
        params[value.id] = value.value;
    });

    for(var prop in params) {
        alert(prop + " = " + params[prop]);
    }
});
```

Notice: params is an object now not an array.

With this -

```
<input name="first_name" id="firstname" value="Your first name." type="text" class="medium"/>
<input name="last_name" id="lastname" value="Your last name." type="text" class="medium"/>
```

Comment: i need to use strings for the key names

Comment: @luqita: Did you check the second one?

Comment: thanks, not exactly what i was looking for but gave me the idea to send it with JSON.

Answer (score -1):

You can't simply pass a variable to the server, you need to serialize it into `name, value` pairs, or use JSON.

Comment: i am doing that later, this is to show that the array is empty in javascript

Answer (score -1):

I'm slightly unsure what you're trying to accomplish by creating an array in Javascript like this.

Your best bet is probably to use the JQuery command [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) then grab the data using $_GET